# Measure in circuit SMD capacitor using LCR meter

Tags: lcr

I recently bought an LCR meter BK880.

Is it possible to measure the capacitance of a SMD capacitor in a circuit without removing it?

Comment: Think about your question, if you want to measure a resistor but there's another resistor in parallel with it (you might or might not know this), how will the LCR "know that", I mean, how will it know that it only has to measure the first resistor. Can it only measure the first resistor when there's a 2nd resistor in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on details of the circuit it is attached to, and how that behaves at the various test frequencies and voltages that you have available with that meter.

In general, this is not likely to yield a useful measurement corresponding to the actual capacitance.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to measure a part in circuit.  Not if you want a correct measurement.

---

When you try to measure the capacitance of one part in circuit, you have to remember that there will be other parts in parallel to the one you are trying to measure.  The meter will give you the effective value of all the parts - the one you connect it to and all the ones it is in parallel with.

If you know the circuit, you might be able to tell if there are other parts that could interfere.

Or, just do it the easy way and remove the part from the board.

Answer (score 1):

**If you want accurate reading then it will be better to remove it from the board then test.**

The value of the component tested using LCR or any multimeter got influence by other components placed in parallel to the component we are measuring. So, it will be advisable to remove the component first then test it using LCR meter.